# How to measure the error rate (or fidelity) of a particular gate (such a H, T) by Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, error-mitigation

We know the calibration data of IBM's quantum devices can be retrieved through the randomized benchmarking method, which is included in Qiskit. However, the calibaration data about gates just gives the average error rate of all the single-qubit gates or two-qubit gates. If I want to get the error rate of a specific single qubit gate, such as H gate, what should I do? The randomized benchmarking method doesn't seem to work.